# Regular Expression to find value between slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to find the value between 2 forward slashes.  The value could be `xx/a/xx`, `xx/ab/xx` or `xx/c/xx`

I just want to grab the value between those 2 slashes, the 'xx' could be any character since this is part of a pathname in the url.  Here is what I have so far but it is not working.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var match = pathname.match(/\/(\w+)\//i)
```

Comment: Can the character you wish to match be a slash?

Comment: in perl that regex would be like this `/\/(.*)\//` - you put a backslash before the forward slash to "escape" it so it gets treated as a normal character and not a special.

Comment: "*Here is what I have so far but it is not working.*" — How exactly is not working? What's the current result? What did you expect instead?

Comment: What's not working about the regex? It seems fine to me.

Comment: please define "not working".  On this page your code produces `questions`, but you need to remember that `window.location.pathname` _includes the leading slash_

Comment: @AmalMurali Sorry about that, what I mean to say is that my regular expression is returning null.  I am sure that I have not written it correctly but have been struggling with the correct expression to find a string that contains some character between 2 slashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need a regex here, use `split`:

```
var s = 'xx/ab/xx'
var r = s.split('/')[1];
//=> ab
```

Comment: If you want to know regex then `s.match(/\/([^\/]*)(?=\/)/)[1];` will work.